# ffmpeg permission denied though the user has permission

Tags: python, ffmpeg, flask, ubuntu-14.04, permission-denied

I have installed ffmpeg in my server running ubuntu 14. my flask app project root is at /var/www/project/
i am able to upload files and my python scripts are able to write new files, but when i run ffmpeg in my script it gives permission denied. 
Also running the below line in terminal

```
ffmpeg -i path/to/inputfile /path/to/outputfile & ps aux | grep ffmpeg 

gives the user running the process is "ubuntu" which has write access to the project folder and its subfolders. As i told you other python script run by user "ubuntu" is able to create file.
```

permission denied error happens in both cases(python script and directly in terminal)

**update**: 
also looking at the confusion with the permissions, is there a way i can run the app from /home/ubuntu/project instead of /var/www/project. i am using mod_wsgi with apache for my flask-app.

Answer (score 0):

right now i have added sudo and it is working fine, though i am not sure running ffmpeg as sudo would cause any security issue. Anyone please clarify on this.

```
 cmd='sudo ffmpeg -i '+f_name+' -acodec '+job['audio_ff']+' -b:a '+job['audio_bps']+'k -       b:v '+job['video_bps']+'k -s '+job['res_width']+'x'+job['res_height']+' '+new_file

 p=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The files which are created by your app resides in the var/www/project and these need administrative privilege, if you want to read/access them. Without using sudo you cannot access the administrative protected files.

You can change the rights of the files created by your app to be accessed by ffmpeg without sudo or change the ownership to your username with chown..

Have you checked if your ffmpeg executables have permissions for all the users?

Comment: I already have changed the ownership of the whole project folder recursively to a group and added the user running the app into that group. the whole folder is owned by the new group. Still it gives permission denied.